# error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'enemyHealth' used

Tags: c++

So I'm having some trouble figuring out why exactly I'm getting this error.
I've been programming for about a week now and made this VERY simple game.
I just can't figure out why it's spouting off this error.

Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void battleResults(int enemyHealth);
void battleLoop(int health, int enemyHealth, string selection);
void characterSelection(int health, int enemyHealth, string selection);

int main()
{
// MUH STRINGS
string selection;
string enemy;

// MUH INTS
int health;
int enemyHealth;

cout << "***ULTIMATE COMBAT SIMULATOR***\n";
cout << "***CODED BY OCELOT TOES 2017***\n";

Sleep(1000);

characterSelection(health, enemyHealth, selection);

battleLoop(health, enemyHealth, selection);

battleResults(enemyHealth);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

void characterSelection(int health, int enemyHealth, string selection)
{
string enemy;

cout << "Please choose your race, human or monster!\n";

cin >> selection;

if ((selection == "human") || (selection == "Human"))
{
    cout << "***HEALTH***\nHuman = 1000  Monster = 625\n";
    cout << "You have higher health, but lower attack!\nYou also deal a 
    small amount of damage even when blocking.\n";
    enemy = "monster";
    selection = "human";
    health = 1000;
    enemyHealth = 625;
}
else if ((selection == "monster") || (selection == "Monster"))
{
    cout << "***HEALTH***\nHuman = 1000   Monster = 625\n";
    cout << "You have higher attack, but lower health!\n";
    enemy = "human";
    selection = "monster";
    health = 625;
    enemyHealth = 1000;
}
else
{
    cout << "I'm too lazy to make the game figure out typing errors or just 
    turds, so now you can exit :)\n";
    system("PAUSE");
}

Sleep(1000);

cout << "Okay, so you're a " << selection << ".\n";

Sleep(1000);

cout << "You're fighting a " << enemy << ".\n";

Sleep(1000);

cout << "Let's get this fight started!\n";
}

void battleLoop(int health, int enemyHealth, string selection)
{
// RNG BABY
static mt19937 randomGenerator(time(NULL));
uniform_int_distribution<int> humanAttack(100, 150);
uniform_int_distribution<int> monsterAttack(175, 275);
uniform_real_distribution<float> defenseMultiplier(0.25f, 0.50f);

string uiCombatStatus;
int aCombatStatus;
int damageDealt;
int damageReceived;

while ((health > 0) && (enemyHealth > 0))
{
    cout << "What would you like to do?\nAttack or Defend: " << endl;
    cin >> uiCombatStatus;

    if ((uiCombatStatus == "attack") || (uiCombatStatus == "Attack"))
    {
        aCombatStatus = 1;
    }
    else if ((uiCombatStatus == "defend") || (uiCombatStatus == "Defend"))
    {
        aCombatStatus = 0;
    }

    if ((aCombatStatus == 1) && (selection == "human"))
    {
        damageDealt = humanAttack(randomGenerator);
        damageReceived = monsterAttack(randomGenerator);
        cout << "You chose to attack! You attack for: " << damageDealt << 
        ".\n";
        cout << "The enemy hits you for: " << damageReceived << ".\n";
        enemyHealth = enemyHealth - damageDealt;
        health = health - damageReceived;
        cout << "Enemy's health is at: " << enemyHealth << ".\n";
        cout << "Your health is: " << health << ".\n";
    }
    else if ((aCombatStatus == 0) && (selection == "human"))
    {
        damageDealt = humanAttack(randomGenerator) - 70;
        damageReceived = monsterAttack(randomGenerator) * 
        defenseMultiplier(randomGenerator);
        cout << "You chose to defend! You dealt a small amout of damage: " 
        << damageDealt << ".\n";
        cout << "The enemy hits you for: " << damageReceived << ".\n";
        enemyHealth = enemyHealth - damageDealt;
        health = health - damageReceived;
        cout << "Enemy's health is at: " << enemyHealth << ".\n";
        cout << "Your health is: " << health << ".\n";
    }

    if ((aCombatStatus == 1) && (selection == "monster"))
    {
        damageDealt = monsterAttack(randomGenerator);
        damageReceived = humanAttack(randomGenerator);
        cout << "You chose to attack! You attack for: " << damageDealt << 
        ".\n";
        cout << "The enemy hits you for: " << damageReceived << ".\n";
        enemyHealth = enemyHealth - damageDealt;
        health = health - damageReceived;
        cout << "Enemy's health is at: " << enemyHealth << ".\n";
        cout << "Your health is: " << health << ".\n";
    }
    else if ((aCombatStatus == 0) && (selection == "monster"))
    {
        damageReceived = humanAttack(randomGenerator) * 
        defenseMultiplier(randomGenerator);
        cout << "You chose to defend!\n";
        cout << "The enemy hits you for: " << damageReceived << ".\n";
        health = health - damageReceived;
        cout << "Enemy's health is at: " << enemyHealth << ".\n";
        cout << "Your health is: " << health << ".\n";
    }
}
}

void battleResults(int enemyHealth)
{
if (enemyHealth <= 0)
{
    cout << "***YOU WIN!***" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "***YOU LOSE!***" << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: And the error occurs where?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @YosefMac: Look at the title.

Comment: I am reading the title. The error message states that your local variable called `enemyHealth` is used before it gets initialised. You have such a local veriable, it gets used in `characterSelection(health, enemyHealth, selection);` as a call-by-value parameter, before being initialised. I fail to see what is unclear about that. Initialise it before using it, error should go away. Or make the parameter a reference, since you seem to write to the variable inside the function. But initialising is recommended in that case, too.

Comment: Should have started with this: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2):

- In `main`, you created an uninitialised variable named `enemyHealth`, and passed it to a function.
- Then, in that function, you gave the resulting *copy* a value. Then you returned from the function.
- Back in `main`, you're using the old, uninitialised variable again.
- Then, you pass it to another function, which attempts to read the value.
  However, that value is **indeterminate** because, contrary to your belief, you never set it!

I think perhaps you intended to pass by reference instead, so it's just the one variable at all times.

This is actually a compiler *warning* that's been promoted to an error by some setting. But that's good!

By the way, indenting your code will make it so that we can read it without sacrificing life expectancy.

Comment: It's actually indented in my compiler but I'm still learning the ropes of stackoverflow's formatting, my bad!

Comment: @OcelotToes: You were presented with a preview pane that you had to scroll past in order to reach the "Submit" button...

Comment: I never claimed to be a smart man... or a man at that... I'll improve on that for the future. Thanks for the help!